# Capture audio stream from multiple virtual audio devices simultaneously

Tags: c++, windows, audio-streaming, multimedia

I have an external utility (no source code) which receives audio streams from the UDP ports (up to 256 channels) and is able to play the audio using virtual audio devices (one for each channel).
My requirement is to capture the audio from the virtual devices and retransmit the stream via UDP to another PC.

I wrote a C++ program using windows wave in interface which captures only one channel chosen as input in windows settings.
Is there a way to do it for multiple channels simultaneously?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that you won't be able to reliably keep these devices in-sync, assuming they are independent devices.  Is that a requirement for your project?

Comment: @Brad I haven't such requirement